# move large numbers of records into msmq?

Tags: sql-server-2008, msmq

What is the fastest way to move large number of records (talking in the order of millions) into msmq? We use Sql server 2008 r2. What comes to mind is to use integration services - using a message queue task, which I'm not familiar with.

I've stumbled on a similar question, but I don't think it answers to the point:

[Bulk database rows to message queue for long running operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029836/bulk-database-rows-to-message-queue-for-long-running-operation)

Comment: How many messages will be in MSMQ waiting to be processed? Storing millions of messages in a transport system like MSMQ to be processed at a later date is not what I'd recommend.

Comment: There is no gap of days as such for the messages to get processed. We'd want to use msmq since we want to avoid writing synchronization/transactional code at the db level. We are also thinking of scaling out in terms of number of consumers that can process those millions of records in short time.

Comment: You will need to ensure the system can handle the peak load you're planning to put through it, taking into account network outages which could stop the consumers removing messages. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/29/what-are-msmq-s-limits-if-i-had-a-farthing-for-every-time.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

1. Use SSIS msmq task.
2. Write a component in .net which does this and register it in SQL CLR.

I prefer the first option.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by serialized.

Comment: It's a single queue. Even if messages are sent concurrently on different threads, I reckon you'll have no control over that, or the atomicity of the messages themselves. It may batch or not. Not sure you need to be concerned about this though. I imagine data will be delivered in order it's read.

Comment: order is not important here. I want to be able to put all "records" on queue in the shortest time possible

Comment: I'm sure SSIS will employ whatever is the most efficient method to write the queue.